# can't add summary when using swagger 3 for api platform documentation

Tags: symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I want to add a documentation for my API Platform using swagger 3 .
My api config file :

```
api_platform:
    # The title of the API.
    title: 'API title'
    # The description of the API.
    description: 'API description'
    # The version of the API.
    version: '0.0.0'
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    patch_formats:
        json: ['application/merge-patch+json']
    swagger:
        versions: [3]
    collection:
        pagination:
            enabled: false
            items_per_page : 20
            client_enabled: true
            client_items_per_page: true
            items_per_page_parameter_name: "count"
    eager_loading:
        enabled: false
```

In my Entity i add itemOperations and i tried to add summary :

```
 itemOperations={
 *          "get"={"method"="GET"},
 *          "put"={"method"="PUT"},
 *          "delete"={"method"="DELETE"},
 *          "increment"={
 *         "method"="post",
 *         "path"="/invoices/{id}/increment",
 *         "controller"="App\Controller\InvoiceIncrementationController",
 *         "swagger_context"={
 *             "summary"="my text"  // <<<<<-------- want to add a text
 *         }
 *       }
 *     },
```

I couldn't add the text but when i downgraded the swagger version to 2 i got my text.

How to add a summary for swagger 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For swagger v3 instead `swagger_context` use `openapi_context`

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!